# Query Active Directory with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

This is my first time querying AD with SQL Server.  Sadly, it's not a straightforward Distro List that I need to find.  It contains 2 hyphens (--), which is obviously interpreted by SQL as a comment.  Anyone know how to get around this?

```
SELECT
*
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'SELECT Mail, ADsPath FROM ''LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com'' 
WHERE memberof=''CN=[LDAP://CN=[WSTMSP -- Care RM Staff],OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=West Division,DC=domain,DC=com],OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,OU=West Division,DC=domain,DC=com'' ')
```

Comment: When I type your query in, it looks ok to me. No comments mid-string. Are you getting an error, or is the string breaking in the middle because of the hyphens?

Comment: I was getting an error yesterday.  I thought it was because the double hyphen were being translated as a comment.  This morning it's working so I must have mistyped something.  Thanks for looking at it.